# jquery setInterval problem, called only after complete each loop

Tags: jquery, setinterval, each

I have an `each()` function and I want to update a `div` with the counter of the current `each` element. The problem is that `setInterval()` is called only after the `each` loop finishes.

How can I solve this? Thanks a lot in advance.

```js
function Time($div, c) {
  $div.html(c);
  clearInterval(id)
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div[name="chkstampa' + arg + '"]').each(function() {
    var c = count;
    var $div = $('#div_count');
    
    id = setInterval(function() {
      Time($div, c);
    }, 500);

    if ($(this).jqxCheckBox('checked') == true) {
      if (count == totchecked) last = 1;
      idsfattura += ";" + $(this).attr('idFattura');

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/home/stampa_fatturamultipla",
        data: {
          post_idfattura: $(this).attr('idFattura'),
          post_tipo: '',
          post_count: count,
          post_last: last,
          post_idsfattura: idsfattura
        },
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function() {},
        success: function(msg) {
          if (count == totchecked) {
            //window.open(msg);
            document.location.reload();
          }
          count++;
        },
        complete: function(data) {
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert("error: " + errorThrown);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Then call it immediately using `Time($div, c)`

Comment: 1) `count and `arg aren't defined anywhere? 2) Making AJAX requests in a loop is a very bad idea as it floods your server with requests. Aggregate all data in to a single request and sent that. Return all data in a single response and update all elements in the UI from there.